# Sent to wrong btc address help!

Tags: transactions

I sent my btc to another address which i found it unspent on block chain how do i return it to my account? I contacted coinjar my wallet and still have no response 1 week!

---

I downloaded bitcoin core and used the address[recieve] to finalise the transaction so im not sure why its not in my wallet as the address i got was from my bitcoin core wallet?

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to reverse a transaction once it has been confirmed. Do you control the address that you sent the bitcoin to? If not, then you will need to contact the person (or business) that controls that address, and ask them to return your funds.

Comment: I downloaded bitcoin core and used the address[recieve] to finalise the transaction so im not sure why its not in my wallet as the address i got was from my bitcoin core wallet?

Answer (score 0):

if you mistyped the address and it was somehow still valid (very low probability but still possible) you are definitely screwed. but just finding it "unspent" on a blockchain explorer doesn't mean anything went wrong; it just means the recipient is holding on to it. how about giving more details as to what happened?

Comment: The probability of a mistyped address being valid is about 1 in 4 billion.

Answer (score 0):

You may have entered a invalid address by accident, there is a VERY low probability it was valid, so it is probably unspent at this moment.

However, once it is sent, its sent. There is no way to reverse it.

Answer (score 0):

If the transaction still in mempool then you should be able reverse it but if it on blockchain then u cannot reverse it